# Error keeps appearing when trying to install pygame

Tags: pygame

I am trying to install Pygame on my system but I keep getting this error message

I've deleted and reinstall python and tried several versions of pygame to install but I keep getting the same error message

pip install pygame

```
Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x86"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3ck287c\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3ck287c\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3ck287c\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\Mahdi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h3ck287c\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
1-if you didnt install the pygame file from here:
  https://www.pygame.org/download.shtml
2-extract the file and open it
3-you will see a python file called setup
4-run it with python and it should install
5-to check if it installed run this code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

def main():
   pygame.init()

   DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)

   WHITE=(255,255,255)
   BLUE=(0,0,255)

   DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

   pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE,(200,150,100,50))

   while True:
       for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type==QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()
       pygame.display.update()

main()
```

you should see a blue rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Remove pygame.init() from the loop

```
pygame.init()
def main():
     DISPLAY
```

and then continue your program

Comment: @Rabbid76 What editor are you using? If you are using pycharm I can definetly help you

Comment: @Rabbid76 I understand the question now, but if he were using Pycharm he would not use a command to install it, it would be more likely that he would download the file and add a new path to his python in pycharm. I struggled with this on my own and that is why I know how to help him on that.